# Do action when vibration finish his pattern

Tags: android

Is there a way to do action specificly I want to set global boolean to true, when vibration finish his job ? Example of vibration function :

```
private void Vibration () {
        if(vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
            long ms[] = {0,50,60,50}; // 0 delay, vibrate(40 ms), sleep(60 ms), vibrate(40 ms)
            vibrator.vibrate(ms,-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do after vibration ?

Comment: I wanna set " private boolean check; " to true

Comment: well, what is stopping you from doing so ?

Comment: Well seems like it set to true before vibration end, even when I put it in next line.  Because as far I know vibration.vibrate(..) should execute fully before next line or I am wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TimerTask` with [`schedule (TimerTask task,long delay)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long)) to trigger it when your vibration duration is over and do what you want to do when task is triggered

```
private void Vibration () {
        if(vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
            long ms[] = {0,50,60,50}; // 0 delay, vibrate(40 ms), sleep(60 ms), vibrate(40 ms)
            long delay = 0+50+60+50;
            vibrator.vibrate(ms,-1);
            Timer timerObj = new Timer();
            TimerTask timerTaskObj = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                   //check =true;
                   // executed after the given delay 
                }
            };
            timerObj.schedule(timerTaskObj, delay);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mjafko i am glad that i could help , happy coding